# Google Maps v3 Shapes

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to take a string which has shape option information and create the shape on my Google Map application.

The string is made by splitting an array that was built from a local text document.

The string appears as:
Circle{center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.041872419557094, -87.6046371459961),radius:5197.017394363823,fillColor: '#000000',strokeWeight: 1,strokeColor: '#000000',map:map};

The function I have to take such string and make the shape appears as:

```
function loadDrawings(evt)
{
    var f = evt.target.files[0];

    if (!f) 
    {
        alert("Failed to load file");
    } 
    else if (!f.type.match('text.*')) 
    {
        alert(f.name + " is not a valid text file.");
    } 
    else 
    {
        var r = new FileReader();
        r.onload = function (e) 
        {
            var contents = e.target.result;
            var drawings = [];
            var drawing;
            var drawingType;
            var shape;
            var shapeOptions;

            drawings = contents.split(";");
            for (i = 0; i < drawings.length - 1; i++) {
                drawing = drawings[i].toString();
                drawingType = drawing.substr(0, drawing.indexOf('{'));
                if (drawingType == "Circle")
                {
                    shapeOptions = drawing.substr(6);                //UNIQUE TO CIRCLE
                    shape = new google.maps.Circle(shapeOptions);
                    shape.setMap(map);
                }                    
            };
        }
        r.readAsText(f);
    } 
}
```

My issue is shapeOptions as a string does not work in the above syntax for creating the Circle.  However, if I take the contents of the string, which is:

{center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.041872419557094, -87.6046371459961),radius:5197.017394363823,fillColor: '#000000',strokeWeight: 1,strokeColor: '#000000',map:map}

And directly enter it, the shape appears.

Do I need a certain variable type for my shapeOptions for this to work? I know that the new google.maps. requires (), but I have had no luck creating a  variable from my string.  Am I missing something here?

Much appreciation for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `shapeOptions` string is a JavaScript object literal, so you can `eval()` it to get the object:

```
shapeOptions = eval( '(' + drawing.substr(6) + ')' );
```

Since it has `map:map` in it, you don't need the subsequent `setMap()` call.

Also, you're missing a `var` for the `i` variable. I don't really recommend the coding style where all the `var` statements go at the top of a function. I find it error-prone; it's too easy to omit a `var` without noticing it. (I know some famous JavaScript experts insist that `var` at the top is the *only* way to do it, but they fail to see the tradeoffs involved.)

You don't need the `.toString()` on `drawings[i]`. It's already a string.

You have two different brace styles. Best to pick one and stick with it. For JavaScript, putting the `{` on a line by itself is not recommended, because this code will not do what you expect:

```
return  // hoping to return an object literal - but it doesn't!
{
    a: 'b',
    c: 'd'
}
```

Whereas this code does work correctly:

```
return {
    a: 'b',
    c: 'd'
}
```

Since you are using `FileReader`, I think it's safe to assume you also have `.forEach()` available.

You can replace the code that uses `.indexOf()` and the hard coded length with a regular expression.

Putting all that together, you might end up with code like this:

```
var r = new FileReader();
r.onload = function( e ) {
    e.target.result.split(";").forEach( function( drawing ) {
        var match = drawing.match( /^(\w+)({.*})$/ );
        if( ! match ) return;  // unrecognized
        var type = match[0], options = eval( match[1] );
        switch( type ) {
            case "Circle":
                new google.maps.Circle( options );
                break;
        }
    });
}
r.readAsText( f );
```

But you may be able to take it a step further. So far we're looking at a `Circle` (line breaks added for readability):

```
Circle{
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(
        38.041872419557094,
        -87.6046371459961
    ),
    radius:5197.017394363823,
    fillColor: '#000000',
    strokeWeight: 1,
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    map:map
}
```

With only a simple change, that could be executed as JavaScript directly. You just need the 'new google.maps.' at the beginning and `()` around the object literal:

```
new google.maps.Circle({
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(
        38.041872419557094,
        -87.6046371459961
    ),
    radius:5197.017394363823,
    fillColor: '#000000',
    strokeWeight: 1,
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    map:map
})
```

I assume you will have other drawing types as well? Will they all map directly to `google.maps.*` objects like `Circle` does? If so, you could simply do:

```
var r = new FileReader();
r.onload = function( e ) {
    e.target.result.split(";").forEach( function( drawing ) {
        eval( drawing.replace(
            /^(\w+)({.*})$/,
            'new google.maps.$1(\$2)'
        ) );
    });
}
r.readAsText( f );
```

Comment: Michael, thank you for your prompt and helpful reply.

shapeOptions = eval('(' + drawing.substr(6) + ')');

Comment: Michael, first let me thank you for your reply.  It is very beneficial and has helped me better understand how to achieve more with less (something I definitely need to do more of).  Not as an excuse, but I hope when I have progressed passed being a beginner, I will become more efficient with my scripting.

Prior to your edit, I was unaware of the bracket styling.  I assure you that I will begin to use your recommendation.

Again, thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Whoops, I forgot those parentheses. Thanks for catching that, I added them to the answer for any future readers. Otherwise, I'm glad my comments were helpful. Keep up the good work!